# Can I configure Ubuntu Server 22.x to be accessed via xRDP or VNC and present the same full-featured Gnome UX as Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

Is there a way I can install Ubuntu Server 22.x on a remote VM and have multiple users connecting to it via VNC or xRDP in a way that each user logs in and starts its own session in isolation? And is there a way to make that have the same Gnome user experience that would be provided if they were using Ubuntu Desktop?

In an experiment, I have been able to configure xRDP and access it remotely, but it started a Gnome session that doesn't look like the Ubuntu Desktop experience. The layout is different, the wallpaper is not loaded, the 'dock' is at the bottom of the screen instead of the left side (which would be the standard).

Comment: Please be precise with details; 22.04 & 22.10 are different releases from different cycles (*the two year development that concluded with 22.04 LTS started in May 2020, 22.10 is the first non-LTS release that will conclude with 24.04 LTS release into the future when its development concludes*).  If you install Desktop packages to a Server system, you can change the Server into a Desktop system (*it'll depend how & what is actually installed as to what changes occur; plus release details can again have minor differences given packages are made for a given release*)